# How to inject global variables with Webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I need a specific instance of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), generated at compile-time, to be made available to the code that I'm bundling with webpack. My use cases if for an instance of `Map`, but the question holds for any variable, really.

- [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) won't work because my instance of `Map` doesn't survive stringification. I could deserialize/serialize, but that seems inefficient.
- [`options.externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) won't work because I'm not `require`ing an external module to be ignored by the bundler.

I've been able to get this working by setting a value on `global`, but I'm not sure this is the best way to go about this.

Here's a pathetically-contrived example:

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const myVar = new Map([
  ['a test value', () => {}]
]);

// is there a better way?
global.myVar = myVar;

module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: './output.js'
  },
  target: 'node',
}
```

**entry.js**:

```
console.log(global.myVar) //=> Map { { "a test value", [Function] } }
```

---

In my real-world app, my `Map` value crawls the file system and builds a mapping of regexes and handlers. This should happen at **compile** time and is a constant mapping, so I want to consume it in my code-to-be-bundled as a constant.

I tried building the `Map` inside `entry.js`, but got all sorts of weird "Cannot find module" errors, I think mostly because the function I'm using to build the `Map` in the first place heavily abuses dynamic requires in a directory tree outside webpack's purview.

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Alternative: Use a stringifyable data structure (so that you can use the define plugin) and convert that to a map at runtime.

Comment: @FelixKling In my case, `Map` is perfect, since I can use Regexs as keys and implement a `find` combinator to quickly find the entry that matches the regex. As these are used as route handlers for an API, I really don't want to sacrifice this flexibility in my app design because of my build tooling. ;)

Comment: You don't have to (you can convert the map to an array of arrays). But if the values are not stringifyable, that won't help anyway.